# getting error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: selenium-webdriver

While executing a basic program to launch a browser, I'm getting the below error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.io.OutputStream org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.getLogOutput(java.lang.String)'

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod com.Tatras.CSSL.TestCases.UserLogin.Setup
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.io.OutputStream org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.getLogOutput(java.lang.String)'
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.createDriverService(ChromeDriverService.java:356)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.createDriverService(ChromeDriverService.java:160)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:508)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:51)
    at com.Tatras.CSSL.BaseClass.BaseClass.IntializeBrowser(BaseClass.java:27)
    at com.Tatras.CSSL.TestCases.UserLogin.Setup(UserLogin.java:22)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:69)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:390)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:325)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.runConfigMethods(TestInvoker.java:810)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:577)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:227)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:957)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:200)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:848)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:443)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:437)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:397)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:336)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1280)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1200)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1114)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1082)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

I tried to create a new project again, update and degrade the dependencies but I'm still getting same error again & again with all the three browsers.

The code

```
public class BaseClass {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static WebDriverWait wait;
    public static org.slf4j.Logger logger;

    public WebDriver IntializeBrowser(String browserName) {
        logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseClass.class);
        if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("edge")) {
            driver =  new EdgeDriver();
        } else if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")) {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(15));
        
        String launch_browser =  ReadPropertyFileData.ApplicationUrl();
        driver.get(launch_browser);

        return driver;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the entirety of the code in your project? If so, it looks like something didn't get installed correctly or is out of sync/incompatible with other libraries. Please edit your question and list the libraries and versions that you have in your project.

Comment: using these version of dependencies     <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
   <version>4.16.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
   <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
   <version>5.6.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Please do **not** use the comment space for adding such info; **edit & update** your question instead.

Comment: You have no other code in the project other than `BaseClass`? What is calling `BaseClass` to initialize it? Where is `org.slf4j.Logger` coming from? I don't see that in your dependencies. Also, you no longer need to use webdrivermanager because [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager) is now built into Selenium as of 4.6.